# C# DataTable delete row

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I have DataTable `participantAccounts` which is not connected to any database or something.

How can I delete a row from it?

This is not working :

```
for (int i = participantAccounts.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
          DataRow dr= participantAccounts.Rows[i];
          if (Equals(dr["sellrMembId"].ToString(), itemId))
            participantAccounts.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
        }

        participantAccounts.AcceptChanges();
```

It acts like everything is fine but row still remains in DataTable.
I also tried `dr.Delete()` but that neither works.
When I try `participantAccounts.Rows.Remove(dr)` I get an exception `The given DataRow is not in the current DataRowCollection.`

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try `DataRow dr = participantAccounts.Rows[i]; if (Equals(dr["sellrMembId"].ToString(), itemId)) { dr.Delete(); }`

Comment: the problem is that you delete rows from the table while looping on it. You should instead use a for each and remove the row using the `.Remove([Datarow])`

Comment: Michael - I tried but no effect

Comment: Franck - when I use `Remove` I got an exception  `The given DataRow is not in the current DataRowCollection. (I used it outside of cycle)`

Comment: @Maarty do you still call `participantAccounts.AcceptChanges();` after `foreach` loop?

Comment: i don't delete rows anymore, or rarely, I usually have objects. But when i need to delete i do an inverse select as in if i want to delete all records where price is more than 100 i do (pseudo) `myDatatable = myDatatable.Select("Price < 100");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.
IT had nothing to do with way how rows were deleted.

```
DataTable dt = participantAccounts;
        dt.Rows.Remove(dt.Rows.Find(itemId));
        participantAccounts = dt;
```

the problem was, I think, participantAccounts was a viewstate (.ASP) , and it for that reason it was not updated with direct approach.

Thank everyone for help

Answer (score 4):

```
if (participantAccounts.Rows.Contains(itemId))
            {
                DataRow foundRow = participantAccounts.Rows.Find(itemId);
                participantAccounts.Rows.Remove(foundRow);

           }
```

Comment: When I do this approach I get an exception `The given DataRow is not in the current DataRowCollection.`

Comment: What about the value of participantAccounts.Rows.Contains(itemId) ?

Comment: it does contain... foundRow is loaded with my row, but on Remove(foundRow) there is the exception

Comment: Can you tell me the value of foundRow.RowState before the remove statement?

Answer (score 3):

```
for (int i = participantAccounts.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    DataRow dr= participantAccounts.Rows[i];
    if (Equals(dr["sellrMembId"].ToString(), itemId))
    {
        participantAccounts.Rows.Delete();
        participantAccounts.AcceptChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what this code does and how it might address the problem.

Comment: There is absolutely no need to call `AcceptChanges` in loop.

Comment: if we call AcceptChanges() then the table reduce the row number sothat there is no exception at last loop count..

Answer (score 2):

You should use `Delete` instead of `RemoveAt`.

So your code could look like:

```
for (int i = participantAccounts.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
{
      var dr= participantAccounts.Rows[i];
      if (object.Equals(dr["sellrMembId"], itemId))
         dr.Delete();
}

participantAccounts.AcceptChanges();
```

**Note**: your deleted DataRows will present in DataTable and have `RowStatus = Deleted` until you will call `AcceptChanges` method on DataTable. After calling `AcceptChanges`, deleted DataRows will be removed from the table.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.delete%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for reference on `DataRow.Delete` method.

Answer (score 2):

```
int index = -1;

for (int i = participantAccounts.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    DataRow dr= participantAccounts.Rows[i];
    if (Equals(dr["sellrMembId"].ToString(), itemId))
    {
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}

participantAccounts.Rows.RemoveAt(index);
participantAccounts.AcceptChanges();
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the work..

```
dataSet1.Customers.Rows[0].Delete();
```

OR

```
dataSet1.Tables["Customers"].Rows[0].Delete();
```

[How to: Delete Rows in a DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/feh3ed13.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You should use foreach loop to get each row and find particular row which you want to remove. Below is code snippets.

```
foreach (DataRow row in participantAccounts.Rows)
{
   if (row["sellrMembId"].ToString() == itemId)
   {
      participantAccounts.Rows.Remove(row);
      participantAccounts.AcceptChanges();
      break;
   }
}
```